# iOS Messages phone storage usage different from iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, messages

I have a conversation log in my iPhone (iPhone 11 Pro, iOS 14.0.1) that goes back to 2009. iOS says it is occupying 15.96GB:

[image: ios screenshot showing 15.96GB phone storage usage]

I have the phone set to save *everything* in my conversations (e.g.: high resolution images and videos) and I don't want to change this setting.

I want to back it up in iCloud so I upgraded to 200GB and connected my phone to WiFi and a charger. It started displaying the “Uploading messages” message and progress bar at the bottom of the screen. This message and progress bar no longer shows up and it has only uploaded 8.1GB:

[image: ios screenshot showing 8.1GB iCloud storage usage]

This number doesn't change anymore regardless of me charging the phone or not. I don't have Messages iCloud sync activated in any other device. Any idea why this seems to have gotten stuck?

Comment: I wonder if certain kinds of storage (like Messages) is compressed when backed up to iCloud but not compressed on the device itself. After all text compresses *very well.*

Comment: @SteveChambers quite possible. if I activate iCloud messages in my Mac what are the risks of getting sync errors and data loss?

Comment: As I don't use Messages on my Mac, I couldn't tell you. You could get one of those iOS management apps like iMazing or iExplore, they will back up your device and give you access to the backup files.

Comment: the number has been slowly rising in icloud and is now up to 12.5GB. the app still doesn't show a progress bar but I suppose it will be done at some point in the future

Answer (score 1):

The number eventually grew to 15GB after a few weeks. Still no progress bar visible but at least it arrived there so I guess it just takes a long while, even with WiFi.

Comment: Yes and the only way to speed this up is have a Mac on your local network and enable iCloud Caching so the iPhone can offload the content faster to the local content cache - https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-content-caching-on-mac-mchl3b6c3720/mac choose either ***Only iCloud Content*** or ***All Content*** for your messages to be cached securely on the local Mac.